# SQL schedule delete count as write

Tags: sql, sql-delete, schedule

Every time I read about SQL schedules, it always talked about the read and insert operation.

I know that the SQL operation `SELECT` corresponds to the read and that the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` are the writes.

**My question is**: does the `DELETE` operation belong to the write operation talked about in SQL schedules?

Comment: `insert`, `update`, and `delete` are collectively referred to as DML (and there may be other operations as well).  DML stands for *data modification language*, and is one of the components of the SQL language.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thank you for the response it helped a lot.

Comment: the correct definition for DML is Data manipulation language (DML) statements